# How can we detect the host OS type (not the target OS) in Rust?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

There are many ways to detect the target OS, *e.g.* `#[cfg(windows)]`, `#[cfg(unix)]`, `std::env::consts::OS`. For cross-compilation, how can we detect the OS that our Rust program gets compiled on?

Comment: You can't really

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `build.rs` is run on the workstation (not the target), I guess it can detect some workstation related properties then [generate features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-cfg) (`cfg`) that can be tested in the target related code.

For example, here is a `build.rs` script that detects a specific file on your workstation.

```
fn main() {
    // detected on the workstation (not the target)
    if let Ok(_attr) = std::fs::metadata("dummy_file.txt") {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=detected");
    }
    if cfg!(windows) {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=from_windows");
    }
    if cfg!(unix) {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=from_unix");
    }
}
```

Then, `src/main.rs` can test the detected feature.

```
#[cfg(detected)]
fn hello() {
    if cfg!(from_windows) {
        println!("hello from windows with detected file");
    }
    if cfg!(from_unix) {
        println!("hello from unix with detected file");
    }
}

#[cfg(not(detected))]
fn hello() {
    if cfg!(from_windows) {
        println!("hello from windows");
    }
    if cfg!(from_unix) {
        println!("hello from unix");
    }
}

fn main() {
    // run on the target (not the workstation)
    hello();
}
```

Depending on whether `dummy_file.txt` exists or not on the workstation when building the project, the resulting binary for the target will use one version or the other of `hello()`.
Each of these two functions can adapt their behaviour depending on the OS the workstation.